# Help me identify a component

Tags: sensor, components, water, meter

I'm trying to identify a component which I'm not entirely sure what it is.

Here's an image:

[image: Component circled in red]

The component I'm asking about is circled in red.

The product is a reader + transmitter for water meters ([click here](http://waviot.com/product/iot-radiomodules/smart-water-meter-lpwan-radiomodule)).
The sensor somehow either reads the digits from the water meter, or a small rotating disc, to know the water consumption.

Can anybody identify it? My best guess is a linear CMOS sensor, but not sure how would it fit with the application.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the description: _"Radiomodule scans the readings from water meter counter using an **optical sensor**..."_

Comment: I'd suggest its an simple photocell using either DA1 or DA2 to illuminate the dial.

Comment: it looks like a reed switch.

Comment: @Jasen - how will a "reed switch" read anything?

Comment: I'm not saying what it is, I'm saying what it looks like

Comment: @JackCreasey I tend to agree with you, as it also seems to have only two contacts (unless more on the back of it). It's just that I've never seen one that's not round what puzzles me.

Comment: Looks like some of thise fingerprint sensors one sees on laptops...

Comment: @SolarMike it definitely has only two contacts. The only two contact complex device I know of are the Dallas/Maxim one wire devices ....and it's clearly not one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [magnetic reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch).  The device in question is a paddle wheel flow sensor.  The wheel (impeller) has magnets, which pass near the reed switch on each turn.  When a magnet passes, the reed switch closes.  The frequency of closures is proportional to the flow rate.

[image] (picture from [here](http://waviot.com/product/iot-radiomodules/smart-water-meter-lpwan-radiomodule))

> "Radiomodule scans the readings from water meter counter using an optical sensor..."

I suspect a mismatch between the text and the photo.  Maybe, the sensing method changed at some point, but the photo didn't get updated.

Here's a [teardown of another paddle wheel flow meter](http://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/06/teardown-of-paddle-wheel-flow-meter.html).  That one is similar in that it has a magnet in the impeller.  It's different in that it uses a hall effect sensor instead of a reed switch.

Comment: Seems right, it looks suprisingly similar to the 10mm one in this pic: http://www.expo21xx.com/news/wp-content/uploads/meder-automotive-sensor.jpg.
Also, DA2 is the optic sensor (some water meters have plastic dials that turn, also that can be used to count), looking like a QRE1113 (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/QR_QRE1113.GR.pdf)